# Searching 2 words in php

Tags: php

So I have this php page where you can type in a word and if it's in one of the titles or descriptions, it will show the title and description. Now I got this:

```
$title='hoooi';
$description="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.";
if (isset($_GET['zoek'])){
    $zoekwoord=$_GET['zoek'];

if($alles_goed==true){
    $zoekwoordreal= explode(" ", $zoekwoord);
    foreach($zoekwoordreal as $word){
        $zoek_title_en_description=$title . $description;
        if($zoekwoord==""){
        }else{
            $pos=stripos($zoek_title_en_description,$word);
        }
        if($pos!==false){
        echo $title . $description;
                    }
        }
        }
        }
    echo <<<EOT
<table>
<form action="zoek.php" method="get">
    <tr><th>Zoek: </th><td><input type="text" name="zoek" value=""></td></tr>
    <tr><th><input type="submit" value="submit"></td></tr>
</form> 
</table
EOT;
```

This works perfectly but only if I type in one word to search for. Now I want to be able to type in 2 words and if they match, show the title and description. At this moment it's not showing me the title and description when I type in for example:"Lorem is". But when I type in "Lorem" it does show me the title and description. So this means that when I type in 2 words, `$pos==false`. What should I do to make my php page available to search with 2 words?

Comment: stripos will find the position of a substring within a string. So it would find "Lorem ipsum" or "ipsum is", but not "Lorem is" because it is not present as a string. I think you are wanting to do a search for two separate strings (words) within your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `explode()` or `preg_split('/\s+/', ...)` to split your query string into the words and then looping them with a `foreach()` and check each of them.

Comment: It's on you now to try implementing it. I said already "how" but you've to do it now.

Comment: If you can't getting it to work come back with your new code and I'll help you.

Comment: Now you have to loop over your word array `$zoekwoordreal` with `foreach($zoekwoordreal as $word) { /* do your stripos check here */ }`

Comment: When I search 2 words, it shows me the title and description twice.

Comment: When I search 3 words I get it 3 times.

Comment: Okay now you got it more or less. Look at the second code block of @AllenChak. There is the soltion. You have only to do the check and cache the result of it during your loop and afterwards check the state and print it out or not.

Comment: I got it like that more less. I really dont get what I am doing wrong.

Comment: NVM I just closed my foreach too late

Answer (score 0):

Remember that to add a second keyword input box with the name "zoek2"

```
if (isset($_GET['zoek'])){
    $zoekwoord =$_GET['zoek'];
    $zoekwoord2=$_GET['zoek2'];

    if($alles_goed==true){
        $zoek_title_en_description=$title . $description;

        if($zoekwoord!="" && $zoekwoord2!=""){
            $pos=stripos($zoek_title_en_description,$zoekwoord);
            $pos2=stripos($zoek_title_en_description,$zoekwoord2);
        }
        if($pos!==false && $pos2!==false){
            echo $title . $description;
        }
    }
}
```

For the case you want to search multiple keywords and keep using the single input box:
PS: all words will split by `SPACE`, example: "karl is great", total word: 3.

```
if (isset($_GET['zoek']) && !empty($_GET['zoek']) ){
    $zoekwoords = explode(" ", $_GET['zoek']);
    $foundAll = true;

    if($alles_goed==true){
        $zoek_title_en_description=$title . $description;

        foreach( $zoekwoords as $zoekwoord ){
            $pos=stripos($zoek_title_en_description,$zoekwoord);
            if($pos===false){
                $foundAll=false;
                break; //add break to speed up
            }
        }
        if($foundAll !== false){
            echo $title . $description;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a good solution? What if I wanted to search for like 5 words? I have to have 5 textboxes? That cant be right.

Comment: Ummm.... I think that you should ask for "multiple keywords" instead of "2" from your question! For multiple keywords: read my code of lower one.

Comment: If this if `if($pos===false)` is true you can also `break;` cause if one keyword is not found it's over and you don't have to check all the others which are left.

Comment: if (isset($_GET['zoek']) && !empty($_GET['zoek']) ) You are missing a (?

Comment: @Loko There are no missing any `(` OR `)`. @TiMESPLiNTER, thanks for your reminder